# I’m unsure if my local repository is in a correct state to push to my remote

Tags: git, github-pages

I was working on the latest head, which is the same as the origin/head and made several local commits and then rebased into one commit.  It was only then did I realize that I should have created a new branch before committing to main.

I did a `git branch prefixtest`  to create a new branch.  But I’m worried about pushing this because I’m not sure if this is correct, because of the “main” appearing in the latest commit’s log entry.

How can I fix this before pushing to my central repo?

```
commit d6e6a(HEAD -> prefixtest, main)
Author: Me
Date:   Thu Jun 24 14:22:27 2021 -0400

    issue 151

commit b13cba(origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Me
Date:   Thu Jun 17 01:47:58 2021 -0400

    Issue 121
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your main to go back to where the one from the remote is:

```
git branch -f main origin/main
```

That's it.

So, a little more info: Your local branches are *completely separate* from your remote branches. You can place them at will and they won't affect the remote ones.... *unless you push them*. Now, if you would like to keep your main branch in sync with your remote branch, then yes, you definitely need to do what I say as the answer because you should **not** have any revisions on your local branch. But, so that it's clear, there's no mandate (per git itself) for that. It's just that if you use that kind of **workflow**, then you have to stick to that rule.

Comment: So after I change my head I can then create the branch as I should have in the first place?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question really well. The thing is that branches in git are just **pointers** that can be moved around at will. So, if you mess up, like in this case, you can fix it with this recipe. What you should have done is something like: `git checkout -b prefixtest main; * work work work *; git add *; git commit -m "issue 151"; git push origin prefixtest` or something along those lines. And I say along those lines because I am not too fond of keeping a local branch that resembles a remote branch.... so I use different workflows... but that's just me.